# How to turn off proper-case correction on a specific field?

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access-based Employee table and have a field to hold username values.  The username format for the application I'm tracking is FirstinitialLastname ("JDoe").

However, when I enter the username value in my Employee table, Access is automatically changing it to "Jdoe".

Is there a way for Access to accept what is being entered into this field and not change it?  Searching online I see posts for how to turn on proper case, but for this particular field I don't want it to modify what I have entered.

In the near future, this Access database will be split in order to move the data out of Access and into SQL Server.  Will the issue I'm having be alleviated once the data is stored in SQL Server?

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can stop `Name AutoCorrect` from Access Option. Microsoft article here in this link. [Set name AutoCorrect options](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/set-name-autocorrect-options-981b70ef-56ea-47a8-8bb4-a93c10a9d98b#bm3)

[image]

When you type name like `JDoe` then after finishing typing, access automatically correct two capital letter and it show a small smart menu. From that you can also make changes to stop auto correct. See below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to that direction.  When I looked this feature up, it sounded to me like it was for managing changes to table field names, not the data.  No boxes in "Name AutoCorrect Options" are currently checked.  But...seeing your example has me curious.  I'll give that a go and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding the use of Name AutoCorrect Options and the Perform Auto Name AutoCorrect tick box as shown above.
I thought this was the very handy feature that if you had a table originally called Customers (with an s on the end) and had built many queries or forms etc based on this, when you changed the table to Customer (without the s on the end), Access would change all your SQL statements automatically for you on the your queries etc so the database didn't stop working.
Apologies if I am wrong but just wanted to check of a knock on effect because you wanted data entry values to stop being changed too.

One fix may cause a bigger issue is all I am worried about. I recently had a customer with a surname of Teh but Access kept changing his surname to The automatically so I just unticked the box for 'Replace text as you type' to stop that happening. It seems to have worked well.

I really like the Name AutoCorrect option for table or query renames etc as I used to hate having to go in an change all my queries back in the day

Apologies again if I have got the wrong end of the stick on this discussion and gone off on a very unhelpful tangent by misunderstanding things in the first place - my wife tells me I have a habit of doing this and my wife is always right